# What does "SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor WebApplication2.xml" mean?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I receive this error while running the webapplication using JSP servlets:

```
 SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor WebApplication2.xml
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
  at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.<clinit>(FacesInitializer.java:105)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

`FacesServlet` is a JSF servlet, you are trying to build a JSF application but haven't included `FacesServlet` in your project

If you are creating a new JSF project through eclipse, then creata a new `Dynamic Web Project`. After creating, Right click on it and select `Properties`. In the properties window, select `Project Facets` and check JSF version